# React Native Image Not Showing

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to show 5 images equally spaced along the horizontal axis `{flexDirection: row, flex: 1}` The images show up fine if I specify a height and width but I would like to avoid this. **I have referenced other questions similar to this but none of the solutions have worked.** More importantly, I would like to understand what exactly is going on.

Here is a snapshot of where the images go:

[image]

Here is my component:

```
import React from 'react-native';

const {
    Component,
    Text,
    StyleSheet,
    PropTypes,
    View,
    Image,
} = React;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'column',
        height: 100,
        borderColor: '#FFbd00',
        borderWidth: 3,
        marginLeft: 20,
        marginRight: 20,
        marginBottom: 20,
        padding: 5,
        alignItems: 'stretch',
        alignSelf: 'stretch',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    row: {
        flex: 1,
        alignSelf: 'stretch',
        flexDirection: 'row',
    },
    column: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    panel: {
        padding: 5,
        alignItems: 'center',

    },
    name: {
        padding: 5,
        borderBottomColor: '#bbb',
        borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
        borderRightColor: '#bbb',
        borderRightWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    spaces: {
        padding: 5,
        borderBottomColor: '#bbb',
        borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    text: {
        fontSize: 32,
        fontWeight: '300',
    },
    imagesContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'stretch',
    },
    image: {
        flex: 1,
        width: null,
        height: null,
    },
});

export default class ParkingLotItem extends Component {
    constructor(props, context){
        super(props, context);

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View pointerEvents='auto' style={styles.container}>
                <View style={[styles.row, {flex: 1.5}]}>
                    <View style={[styles.column, styles.name, {flex: 2}]}>
                        <Text numberOfLines={1} style={styles.text}>{this.props.lot.name}</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={[styles.column, styles.spaces]}>
                        <Text numberOfLines={1} style={styles.text}>{this.props.lot.available}</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.row}>
                    <View style={[styles.panel, styles.row]}>
                        <View style={styles.imagesContainer}><Image resizeMode={Image.resizeMode.contain} style={styles.image} source={{uri: 'http://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}} /></View>
                        <View style={styles.imagesContainer}><Image resizeMode={Image.resizeMode.contain} style={styles.image} source={{uri: 'http://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}} /></View>
                        <View style={styles.imagesContainer}><Image resizeMode={Image.resizeMode.contain} style={styles.image} source={{uri: 'http://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}} /></View>
                        <View style={styles.imagesContainer}><Image resizeMode={Image.resizeMode.contain} style={styles.image} source={{uri: 'http://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}} /></View>
                        <View style={styles.imagesContainer}><Image resizeMode={Image.resizeMode.contain} style={styles.image} source={{uri: 'http://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}} /></View>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

ParkingLotItem.propTypes = {
    lot: PropTypes.shape({
        name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        available: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    }).isRequired,
};
```

Here is the code that the image and image container use:

```
imagesContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'stretch',
},
image: {
    flex: 1,
    width: null,
    height: null,
},
```

and....

```
<View style={[styles.panel, styles.row]}>
    <View style={styles.imagesContainer}><Image resizeMode={Image.resizeMode.contain} style={styles.image} source={{uri: 'http://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}} /></View>
    <View style={styles.imagesContainer}><Image resizeMode={Image.resizeMode.contain} style={styles.image} source={{uri: 'http://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}} /></View>
    <View style={styles.imagesContainer}><Image resizeMode={Image.resizeMode.contain} style={styles.image} source={{uri: 'http://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}} /></View>
    <View style={styles.imagesContainer}><Image resizeMode={Image.resizeMode.contain} style={styles.image} source={{uri: 'http://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}} /></View>
    <View style={styles.imagesContainer}><Image resizeMode={Image.resizeMode.contain} style={styles.image} source={{uri: 'http://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}} /></View>
</View>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not really 100% clear what your question is exactly, but since you're pulling images from the web, setting the height & width is required because the renderer needs to calculate the space it will need to reserve for it in the view. With locally bundled images, the renderer can retrieve that info itself, so height & width are not required in that case. Hope that at least explains the why.

See [Network Images](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#network-images) in the react native documentation.

Comment: That's makes sense. So you're saying that if it was a locally bundles image I could specify the size relatively but I can't specify it relatively with web images

Comment: Indeed, here's a reference [React Native Docs - Network Images](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#network-images) where it states "Unlike with static resources, you will need to manually specify the dimensions of your image."